# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una foto ocupe todo el div que la contiene? Está dentro de un Grid, pero por algún motivo deja 4px de padding

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

```css
/* las imágenes han de ser cuadradas y las 9 fotos han de verse en una parrilla de 3*3 */

img {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    object-fit: cover;
}


/* .container_fotos es a su vez parent de los <div> que contienen las imágenes y child de .contianer que tiene una columna y tres filas con un width 100% del container */

.container_fotos {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
    width: 525px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0px;

    margin: 2em 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container_fotos">
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/5.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/6.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/8.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="/media/9.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise tu código y para conseguir que se elimine el espacio en blanco que esta debajo de la imagen, solo debes agregar el siguiente código a tu archivo css. `img { vertical-align: middle;}`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona correctamente Andres! Muchas gracias! Si tienes idea de qué puede provocar el comportamiento indicado (ese padding-bottom de 4px), estaría aún más agradecido!

Comment: De forma predeterminadamente las imágenes se alinean hacia el borde superior izquierdo, esto puede causar que en algunos casos las imágenes no cubran todo el espacio disponible del contenedor.